# Node.js issue in version 0.10

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Since we updated from Node 0.8 to Node 0.10 we're seeing these errors:

```
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read' }
Error: read ECONNRESET
 at errnoException (net.js:878:11)
 at TCP.onread (net.js:539:19)
```

I know this error was ignored before 0.10, but I'd like to know
 what's causing this and how I can fix it/debug it?
 Is it a problem on our end (server) closing connections too soon?

Comment: Can you please post your code as well ?